Will renaming fields in looker studio break things?
I have several different data sources coming in to my Looker Studio dashboards. I am considering renaming some fields in Looker Studio in order to organize stuff and establish some naming conventions to make life easier.
My understanding is this won’t break things within my reports, but what about connectors?
Does Looker remember that Field A from a Google Doc originally was Field A when it was first pulled into looker but now is = Field B because I renamed it?
What happens if I reconnect to the data source?
Is this generally an ok idea?

Renaming in looker studio should not impact updating a dashboard as Looker studio uses a Field Id and not field name to identify the field. Although i would recommend a test just incase.
As a bonus if you are using multiple data sources you can allow them use the same filter if the field Id is the same on a calculated field

